# Writing multiline text files in Lua

Tags: file, lua, line-breaks, multiline

I would like to know the best way to make my script write something into a file (lets say `text.txt`) in a way that would always add a line break at the end. When I append text using

```
file = io.open("test.txt", "a")
file:write("hello")
```

twice, the file looks like:

```
hellohello
```

But I want it to look like:

```
hello
hello
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unlike `print`, the new line character isn't added automatically when calling `io.write`, you can add it yourself:

```
file:write("hello", "\n")
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to include a [Newline character sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) every time you call the `write` method like so: `file:write("hello\n")` or so: `file:write("hello", "\n")`. This way, a script such as

```
file = io.open(test.txt, "a")
file:write("hello", "\n")
file:write("hello", "\n")
```

would result in the desired output:

```
hello
hello
```

There are, however, many other solutions to this (some being more elegant than the others). When outputting text in Java, for example, there are special methods such as `BufferedWriter#newLine()`, which will do the same thing in a more cleaner fashion. So if your interested in a different way of achieving this, I suggest you read up on the Lua docs for analogous methods/solutions.